# AngularJs - Injecting child module into other child module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services, angular-controller, angular-module

I have a scenario which might sound stupid but I'm stuck and trying to understanding what might be causing it to not work.

I have an angular app which has three modules for now

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']); //parent module
var reviewModule = angular.module('reviewModule', ['mainApp']);  //child 1
var searchmodule = angular.module('searchmodule', ['mainApp']);  //child 2
```

I have set some configurations and default strings in my parent module (which is mainApp) which i want to use in all its child modules.

On the other hand, my reviewModule and searchmodule (child modules) have separate controllers and services which I'm using on different routes. Now, the problem comes when i want to use one module's service into the other so for example if i do the following

```
var searchmodule = angular.module('searchmodule', ['mainApp', 'reviewModule']);
```

to use reviewModule services in my search module controllers, I get an exception that says

```
Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error
Failed to instantiate module searchmodule
```

Both child modules have the same parent and i want to use one child module into the other child module and couldn't understand why I'm getting this exception.

Update:

I even tried using the line below for module declaration

```
var searchmodule = angular.module('searchmodule', ['reviewModule']);
```

but this causes an exception too.

Comment: this seems backwards, you don't inject the parent into the child, you inject the children into the parent.

Comment: Isn't mainApp the parent module in this scenario having couple of child modules (reviewModule and searchmodule)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is backwards .... add the secondary modules as dependencies of the main module

```
angular.module('reviewModule', []);  
angular.module('searchmodule', []);  

angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute','reviewModule', 'searchmodule']); //parent module
```

All components of all modules are now available anywhere across the app

Alternatively you could have one child load another as a dependency but end result is they all need to be bound to the main application module that gets bootstrapped

Example:

```
angular.module('reviewModule', []);  
angular.module('searchmodule', []);  
// module just to combine other modules
angular.module('myChildModules',['reviewModule', 'searchmodule']);
// add combined modules as dependency of main app module
angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute','myChildModules']);
```

Comment: Ok in this case, what should be the order of declaration of modules? reviewModule then searchmodule and then mainApp module will come in last? I wanted to use something like <div ng-app="searchmodule"> in my views, is that possible then?

Comment: no...you can only have one `ng-app` in page. Think of it all as one big object ... adding dependencies simply adds properties to that object. So the main object needs to include all the sub module proeprties for the app to use them .. and there is only one main object used for the whole application

Comment: Great alright, Just one last thing, I have injected the children into parent as you have described and using the mainApp as ng-app. My services are declared on individual modules (on searchmodule and reviewModule), should i declare these on mainApp as well for them to be available on their controllers?

Comment: no. All those services, directives, controllers etc  are all combined into the master app module now and you can use them anywhere ....exactly the same as if you only had one module